# Put a Tikz downarrow between 2 cells in a table while keeping alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment

I want to have a tikz downarrow that matches any of the next 2 figures:

[image]

[image]

My code with tikz puts the arrow, but breaks the alignment of elements in the first column.
Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tikz}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  \midrule
  \tikzmark{a} a  & 10 & 0 \\
  b & 4 & 6 \\
  a & 7 & 3 \\
  \tikzmark{b}b  & 6 & 4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[->] (a.west-| b.west) -- (b.west);
\end{document}
```

Resulted table:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE. Have a look at the `nicematrix` package if you haven't yet. (Or wait for a little while and I'm sure F. Pantigny will himself post a solution.)

Comment: Now that there's the wonderful `tikzmark` library, it's useless to create a `tikzmark` macro, when you can do it better with `\tikzmarknode`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel, you already have the `tikzmark` library, which works like a charm.
[image: Arrow in tabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
      \toprule
      col1 & col2 & col3 \\
      \midrule
      \tikzmarknode{a}{a}  & 10 & 0 \\
      b & 4 & 6 \\
      a & 7 & 3 \\
      \tikzmarknode{b}{b}  & 6 & 4 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \path(a) --++ (-10pt,0) coordinate (aux) edge[->] (aux|-b);
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by chsk, here is a solution with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{crr}[create-medium-nodes]
  \toprule
  col1 & col2 & col3 \\
  \midrule
  a  & 10 & 0 \\
  bbb & 4 & 6 \\
  a & 7 & 3 \\
  bb  & 6 & 4 \\
  \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [->] ([xshift=-1mm]2-1-medium.west) -- ([xshift=-1mm]5-1-medium.west) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]